# GLFW error 65543: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig. Please make sure you have up-to-date drivers (see aka.ms/mcdriver for instructions)

Tags: 20.04

Whenever I try to enter Minecraft on Ubuntu 20.04 I get this error:

```
GLFW error 65543: GLX: Failed to create context:
GLXBadFBConfig. Please make sure you have up-to-date drivers
(see aka.ms/mcdriver for instructions).
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

while running your launcher, try this :-

If your launcher is apt:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.3 minecraft-launcher
```

If your launcher is jar:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.3 java -jar (your jar filename)
```

Copied from https://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/glfw-error-65543-glx-failed-to-create-context-glxbadfbconfig-solution/